# How to browse and select a file from sdcard using Phonegap 3.0?

Tags: android, cordova

Gone through API of Phonegap 3.0.

I want to browse files from SD card when i click on link or button by using UI

For example:

```
 <p onclick="browseFile()">Upload</p>
```

let assume browseFile() function contains the browsing but require UI implementation.

Or

```
 <input type="file">
```

But when i use input type=file,it is browsing file from Gallery and Music Tracks but not from SD card.

I want that i should be able to select file from SD by using UI when i click on link or button

Can anyone suggest the link for same which give Java Script code along with UI for browsing file from SD card?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no out-of-the-box solution. Unfortunately, you have to build it yourself, using [File API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html).

[Here](http://ramkulkarni.com/blog/file-chooser-dialog-for-phonegap-application/) you have an example, build using jQuery Mobile.

Comment: Dear downvoter. Do you have enough courage to write a comment, what is wrong with my answer? Whether you downvoted it, because you found something wrong in it (what?)? Or only, because you have a bad day, as you found out, that finally you have to do something yourself. There is no ready solution this time and finally you have to get your ass to work? Note to others: Sorry, if someone is offend by my comment, but I really hate people downvoting without expressing clear reason for doing so...

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a ready solution out there in the wild and I needed one for my project, so I wrote this simple library called [FileSelect](https://github.com/jahu00/FileSelect). It's licensed with [WTFPL](http://www.wtfpl.net/about/), so you can use for whatever purpose you want.